# Proving bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$ which has just one limit point is convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My approach to proving this as follows :
What would be your advice on me? Is my proof incorrect/correct, what else should be mentioned etc? I'm just new to analysis in mathematics.

So let $a_n$ be this sequence. We are in $\mathbb R$ so by the Least upper bound property $\inf(a_n)$ and $\sup(a_n)$ exist. Either $\sup(a_n)$ or $\inf(a_n)$ will be achieved as $n$ goes to infinity. Let's say $a_n\to L$ as $n$ goes to infinity. We know this should either be $\sup(a_n)$ or $\inf(a_n)$ as I mentioned above. If let's assume $a_n$ increases to this would be $\sup(a_n)$

Therefore $$\sup(a_n)=L$$

Let's say that there exists another limit $M$ For $M$ to be different than $L$ $M=\inf(a_n)$ should be the case.

But since we assumed $a_n$ is an increasing function, $|a_n-\inf(a_n)|<|a_{n+1}-\inf(a_n)|$ so as $n$ goes to infinity it is impossible for us the reach $\inf(a_n)$ therefore convergence happens only when limit point exists.

If more than two limit points exist, this would show us that $a_n$ is not monotonic, therefore can't converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in what you said:

1. What do you mean by "Either $\sup_n a_n$  or $\inf_n a_n$ will be achieved as $n$ goes to infinity"?
2. $\sup_n a_n$ and $\inf_n a_n$ are not related to the limit points of the sequence $(a_n)$. Example: $a_n = -1, 1, 0, 0,0,\dots $. $\inf_n a_n=-1$, $\sup_n a_n=1$ are not limit points of the sequence $(a_n)$.
3. There can be no subsequence of $(a_n)$ converging to $L = \sup_n a_n$, cf. previous example.

More interesting would be to consider $\liminf_n a_n$ and $\limsup_n a_n$, and to prove that those numbers are equal.

Comment: 1. when $n$ goes to infinity my sequence will be equal to either sup or inf
2. What do you mean they are not related to limit points? you just wrote that it is interesting to consider $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of the sequence?